# How to Curl Trending API from Microsoft Image Search?

Tags: api, curl, azure-cognitive-services, trend

I'm trying to issue a curl for Trending API from Microsoft's Image Search services. From the [docs](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/56b44b8ccf5ff81038d15ce0), it seems like a very simple API. However, I'm getting an error "Trending data not available for your request." I assume I'm missing a parameter.

```
curl "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/trending" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <My-Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key>"
```

Comment: dunno why, but for some reason, the example code shows you should send the weird request body '{body}' , whatever the hell that means. anyway, try adding the parameter `--data-ascii "{body}"`

Comment: The doc's curl example is complete nonsense. You can't use a data option on a GET. The author just cut and pasted without testing. I've found numerous mistakes in their docs.

Comment: actually, GET requests can have a "request body" too, its just extremely rare in practice. to prove this, try running `nc -l -p 1337` , then in another terminal, run `curl 127.0.0.1:1337 -X GET --data-ascii "{body}"`, and you get: `nc -l -p 1337

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.net:1337
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{body}`  - as you can see, a GET request with a request body. nothing in the http specs specifically disallows this, afaik.

Comment: As you may have guessed, the example code is auto-generated, and in this case it's generated incorrectly.  The body should be empty.

I was able to execute the curl command without error.  Was it a transient issue?

Comment: Not a transient issue. I'm still getting the same error. Are you verifying with the same curl in the original message?

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon better documentation on MSDN as opposed to Microsoft Cognitive website. Unfortunately the Cognitive website doesn't have the MSDN information and lacks critical information. Also the `curl` example is badly wrong and simplistic.

[MSDN Trending Images](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695661.aspx)

[MSDN Image Search API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791.aspx)